# JetBrains Toolbox crash on Windows: "Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat"

Tags: jetbrains-toolbox

I've recently updated my graphic card drivers and the JetBrains Toolbox app stopped working.

Sometimes it displays an icon next to the system clock that disappears after a couple of seconds, sometimes it displays a black dialog box, but I managed to select all text and copy it:

```
---------------------------
Toolbox
---------------------------
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize 8, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBehavior(DefaultSwapBehavior), swapInterval 1, profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile)) .
This is most likely caused by not having the necessary graphics drivers installed.    

Install a driver providing OpenGL 2.0 or higher, or, if this is not possible, make sure the ANGLE Open GL ES 2.0 emulation libraries (libEGL.dll, libGLESv2.dll and d3dcompiler_*.dll) are available in the application executable's directory or in a location listed in PATH.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I've checked, the `libEGL.dll`, `libGLESv2.dll` and `D3Dcompiler_47.dll` files are present in the app folder, so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I found the real solution on the [Community forum](https://toolbox-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000704430-Unable-to-run-new-version-of-Toolbox-app-on-machines-with-AMD-video-cards-and-x2-monitors):

> I could solve the problem by moving the following dll's to another folder which is not in the PATH folders.
>
> I move libEGL.dll, libGLESV2.dll, opengl32sw.dll from the folder C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\bin to the new folder -> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\bin\tmp. Or delete it. After moving the files and restarting jetbrains-toolbox.exe, I get a welcome window and then a login window.

Comment: This [bug is tracked](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/ALL-2137) by Jetbrains.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting an environment variable as follows:

```
JETBRAINS_TOOLBOX_NO_SOFTWARE_OPEN_GL = 1
```

or

```
JETBRAINS_TOOLBOX_NO_SOFTWARE_OPEN_GL = true
```

According to [Jetbrains Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/ALL-2137) this bug should be fixed in version 1.7

**Update**

This issue was fixed in **1.7.3593**.

Comment: Thank you, I'm switching the best answer to this one.